# Language Converter for different store?

Tags: language, extensions

I am using magento community Edition 1.9.0.0. I created two different store for English and Spanish. And for Spanish i have added library to convert the data in the Spanish language,
But it not converting whole data like categories, static block etc.

My Question is, is there any way or any extension for that, rather than create separate block and page into a Spanish.

Comment: Are you going to translate all the data in the blocks? Which kind of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an extension for this, you can download it [here](https://github.com/miguelbalparda/MB_Translate/).
It basically adds a new directive to translate blocks and CMS pages instead of creating a separated block for each language/store.

Note this extension only works for a number of cases and you should consider it before using it.